# Solr suggest most common result without returning entire phrase

Tags: solr, autocomplete, lucene

We are looking to implement a suggest drop down for searching a Solr core.
We already have basic search without suggestions implemented, so the cores are set up.  I'm trying to be thorough with the details for my question, without over complicating.

If they are searching a single word, we want the most common single matching word to be suggested.

If they are searching more than one word, we want the most common combined phrase to be suggested.  If the combined phrase isn't there, we want the most common result from one of the words in the phrase.

I was trying to implement a solution for the suggest without having to create another core, where I have to parse out the words, phrases, and counts.

I've looked into spell checker and suggest components.

The problem I've had with suggest is that it only returns the entire field.  We want it to only return as many words as they start typing.

The problem I've had with spell checker is that it doesn't return the correct results if the word is spelled correctly (makes sense, it's a spell checker).  And, if we spellcheck multiple words, they are separated in the results.  If they search more than one word and there's a match we expect both words returned if they are in the same order, and we expecting the user to use the correct spelling.

Documents scenario in the core we are searching:

```
{title: 5ft transparent tape},
{title: 5ft transparent dressing},
{title: onsite training},
{title: tape dispenser},
{title: countertop tape dispenser},
{title: 3ft tape measure},
{title: 5ft tape measure},
{title: 10ft tape measure},
{title: tape media}
```

Only begin to suggest after 3 characters.  Only want 1 result.

```
search: "tra"
returns: transparent
```

^^ idea: returns most common single word that matches, "transparent" appears more than "training".

```
search: "tape me"
returns: "tape measure"
```

^^ idea: returns most common two words that match, "tape measure" appears more than "tape media".

```
search: "cassette tape"
returns: "tape"
```

^^ idea: "cassette tape" does not exist, neither does "cassette", so it returns the most common word that does, "tape".

```
Nice to have, but not required:
search: "tape " (with space)
returns: "tape measure"
```

^^ idea: it knows the space means they are about to enter another word and returns most common two words that start with the first word, "tape measure" appears more than "tape media" and "tape dispenser".

Any ideas on how to achieve this by using the existing core?  I've thought of a way to do it with a new core, by slicing and dicing the data, and creating a suggest component, but I'd like to use the core we have.  Is it possible with a custom token filter? A custom token filter is currently over my head, but I'd give it a shot if it's possible.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to find the correct filter.  ShingleFilterFactory - This filter constructs shingles, which are token n-grams, from the token stream. It combines runs of tokens into a single token.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/filter-descriptions.html#shingle-filter

```html
<fieldType name="spellcheck_phrase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="4" outputUnigrams="false"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Example of the analyzer above:

In: "To be, or not to be."

Tokenizer to Filter: "To"(1), "be"(2), "or"(3), "not"(4), "to"(5), "be"(6)

Out: "To be"(1), "To be or"(1), "To be or not"(1), "be or"(2), "be or not"(2), "be or not to"(2), "or not"(3), "or not to"(3), "or not to be"(3), "not to"(4), "not to be"(4), "to be"(5)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the AnalyzingInfix suggester 
https://lucidworks.com/2015/03/04/solr-suggester/